# join("") invoked upon a string-array with only one element. Purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen this code in a video-tutorial:

```
const navToggle = ["<div id='toggle-menu'>Menu</div>"].join("");
$(".site-header").prepend(navToggle);
```

I understand what it basically does. But what I don't get is the join-invocation.

**What's the purpose of join here?**

Wouldn't be ...

```
const navToggle = "<div id='toggle-menu'>Menu</div>";
$(".site-header").prepend(navToggle);
```

... the same?

Comment: What exactly are you comparing? The code seems to be the same

Comment: Perhaps to convert an Array to a string?

Comment: @phuzi that seems to be the intent but it doesn't make sense in the example given, since there is only a single item in the array. However, were there more than one, then it would be rational.

Comment: You're missing ">" on div closing tag, I don't think it's intentional.

Comment: @Prawin soni: Thanks. Had written it down from screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the purpose of join here?

In that example? None. As you said, you'd be better off with:

```
const navToggle = "<div id='toggle-menu'>Menu</div";
```

In the **general** case, if we assume that the code may add more elements to the array and then do the `join` **later**, it's one way to build a large HTML string:

```
const navToggle = ["<div id='toggle-menu'>Menu</div"];
if (someCondition) {
    navToggle.push("<div>something</div>");
}
if (someOtherCondition) {
    navToggle.push("<div>another thing</div>");
}
const str = navToggle.join("");
```

The result is that `str` is the HTML fragments from the elements combined with nothing in-between them (`join`'s default is to put a comma between them, but passing in `""` overrides that). *(This used to be faster than using string concatenation on some JavaScript engines. It isn't on many any more, and in any case, building this string is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck.)*

But in the code you've shown? It doesn't make any sense at all, no.

Comment: T.J. Crowder: Yep. I doesn't makes sense. I thought it could be some cool trick, worth to know. But perhaps the guy had just copy and paste it himself from somewhere with multiple strings concatenated together.

Comment: maybe it is a dynamic content from the server.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Good thought, but why not join it on the server and just output a string? We'll never know... :-)